# xamarin form ios missing required icon file 167x167

Tags: xamarin.ios, ipa

for my xamarin forms ios project I am getting an error when uploading an ipa file via the application uploader to apple.

missing required icon file ipad of exactly 167x167 for ipad pro.

The weird thing is I have actually included this file already in the media.xcassets.

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Check this icon, Does it fit the Apple's standard for icon? Try to change another image in AppIcons, make sure whether it is the issue of this particular image.

Comment: I created the icons from this site https://makeappicon.com/, they all work except for the error on the one.  I added it in that section where you drop all the images for each icon and thats the only error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I have found regarding this:

First, I would check that all the information found in this article is done (it talks about making sure your .csproj file has the needed references to the files):
https://alexdunn.org/2020/01/06/xamarin-tip-fixing-missing-ios-app-icons/

Second, I would check for miss-match of the case of letters in the file name between the json file in the Assets.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset folder and your ios csproj file.  For example ipad176.png is not the same as iPad176.png.  This article explains it well.
https://blog.mzikmund.com/2020/05/the-mystery-of-the-missing-ios-app-icon/

Finally, neither of these resolved my problem.  For me it seemed that one of the entries in my json file had something weird about it (event though visually it looked fine).  I noticed that every icon entry in the json file AFTER the one that had something weird about it, showed as missing when I attempt to publish the archive.  For me the easiest way to find the offending entry was to look for the first (i.e. earliest in the json list) icon entry that generated a missing icon error message when I published.  Then, I unloaded my iOS project, opened the .csproj file for the iOS project in Visual Studio, and found the entry for that first app icon.  I then copied the file name from the .csproj file and replace the file name in the json with the copied name, saved the json file and magically, I could publish my archive to the App Store.