# How to fix "'CFBundleIconName' is missing" error when uploading ipa to AppStore?

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

**Yet another "'CFBundleIconName' is missing" question**

*I know there are already plenty of questions in *SO* with almost identical title, and many answers suggesting different solutions.*

*The problem behind this, it seems to me, is the use of a very generic message from Apple to cover a very wide range of issues.*

I have an iOS App (written using **Xamarin.Forms**), which is already published in the **AppStore**. Recently, nevertheless, i tried to upload an update and i got an *e-mail* from **Apple** saying

> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
> "Kuhnle Mobile 2021" 2021.1.35242 (35242). Please correct the
> following issues, then upload again.
>
> ITMS-90713: Missing Info.plist value - A value for the Info.plist key
> 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle 'com.kuhnle.mobile2021'.
> Apps built with iOS 11 or later SDK must supply app icons in an asset
> catalog and must also provide a value for this Info.plist key. For
> more information see
> http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7.
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

This is the first time i get this message from **Apple**, but i soon understood i was not the first to do so: Here in *SO* and in other forums i found many solutions for diverse scenarios, but sadly non of the answers i found could fix my issue: i keep getting that same message from **Apple** again and again.

Next i will describe my system and what i have already tried.

### System Description

**Configuration details**

I am building **iOS** app using

- **Xamarin.Forms 5**.0.0.2012
- As IDE i am using **Visual Studio 19** 16.10 on Windows 10.
- To build iOS app i use remote MacMini with **macOs Big Sur 11.4**
- **Xcode 12.5**

**Project details**

As mentioned above i already tried/ruled out all options/solutions i found:

- My project already uses **Asset Catalogs** (since previous uploads to AppStore!), with the 1024 pixels **AppStore** icon included.
- My `Info.plist` already has `XSAppIconAssets` and `CFBundleIconName`, and looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>13.5</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Kuhnle Mobile 2022</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>de</string>
    <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
        <string>de</string>
        <string>en</string>
        <string>es</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.my.AppName</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>2022.1.34969</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>34969</string>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconName</key>
    <string>AppIcon</string>
    <key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
    <string>Light</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>By granting access to the camera you will be able to make photos that you consider specifically relevant for the current document and have them stored directly in its associated folder.</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

- My *~ios.csproj* file indeed includes the `ImageAssets`, and looks like this

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Contents.json">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-60@2x.png">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-60@2x1.png">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-60@3x.png">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-76.png">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-761.png">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-76@2x.png">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-83.5@2x.png">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-AppStore1024.png">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-Notification20.png">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-Notification20@3x.png">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-Settings29.png">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-Small-40.png">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-Small-401.png">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-Small-40@2x.png">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-Small-40@2x1.png">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-Spotlight29@2x.png">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-Spotlight29@2x1.png">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-Spotlight29@3x.png">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
  </ItemGroup>
```

### Problem Description

All this being said: i can Build, Archive and Upload the project using VS, nevertheless, after it has been uploaded i get an e-mail with the message at the beginning of this post. **Furthermore**, when i go and inspect the **ipa** file in my macMini, i can not see any assets included in the **payload** folder and no *Assets.car* file is included neither: trying to upload this **ipa** results in an e-mail from **Apple** with the same message.

I would really appreciate any idea to solve this problem, since i am already dealing with it for a couple of days!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update (16.06.2021)

Visual Studio for Windows v.16.10.2 has been released, and with it a fix to the bug causing the OP problem.

---

### Original Answer

This is a reported bug and a fix is in progress

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/11786

Comment: This is not fixed, I am still getting this issue on VS for Windows 16.10.3.

    ...
   <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
   <string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset</string>
   <key>CFBundleIconName</key>
   <string>AppIcons</string>
</dict>
</plist>

Comment: slightly different but some info in this post might help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50031179/xamarin-form-ios-missing-required-icon-file-167x167/69210148#69210148